# How to GROUP_CONCAT DISTINCT values in a MySQL query that gets number of records and min/max values?

Tags: mysql, query, select, subquery

I'm running MySQL `5.0.88 (Coldfusion8)`

I have a product search which I'm querying `number-of-results` as well as `min/max prices/rebates` across the product table. I also want to include a string of `distinct sizes/colors`, so I can update my search criteria along with displaying the results.

However my GROUP_CONCAT does not return all expected values. I don't know what I'm missing, but it seems it is only returning Distinct `min/max` sizes/colors versus returning `all` Distinct sizes/colors across the recordset.

My product table:

```
 CREATE TABLE dummy (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`iln` VARCHAR(13) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`ean` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`artikelnummer` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`groesse` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`farbe` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`farbnummer` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`preis_ek` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`preis_vk` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`preis_aktuell` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`firma` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`marke` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`nos` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`nos_anzeige` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`aktiv` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`modus` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`bestand` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT '0'
    )
```

Products are listed by EAN, so for example a Shirt in Size S,M,L,XL would have 4 entries like so:

```
  style      ean           size       price      qty
  123      111111111111    S          9.99       12
  123      111111111112    M          9.99        1
  123      111111111113    L          9.99       23
  123      111111111114    XL         9.99        0
```

Here is my Query:

```
 SELECT   COUNT(recordcount) AS total_records
        , MIN(min_price_ek) AS ek_min
        , MAX(max_price_ek) AS ek_max
        , MIN(min_price_vk) AS vk_min
        , MAX(max_price_vk) AS vk_max
        , MAX(max_reb) AS rb_max
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT sizeRange ), ',', 10  ) AS sz_rng
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT colorRange ), ',', 16  ) AS cl_rng 

    FROM (SELECT  a.id AS recordcount
                , a.nos
                , a.nos_anzeige
                , MAX(IFNULL(p.ek, a.preis_ek)) AS max_price_ek
                , MIN(IFNULL(p.ek, a.preis_ek)) AS min_price_ek
                , MAX(IFNULL(p.vk, a.preis_vk)) AS max_price_vk
                , MIN(IFNULL(p.vk, a.preis_vk)) AS min_price_vk
                , ROUND( MAX(  ( IFNULL(p.ek, a.preis_ek) - IFNULL(p.vk ,a.preis_aktuell) ) /  IFNULL(p.ek, a.preis_ek)  ),2) AS max_reb
                , a.groesse AS sizeRange
                , zu.systemfarbe AS colorRange 

                FROM artikelstammdaten a

                # currency join
                LEFT JOIN preislisten p ON 
                    p.iln = a.iln 
                AND p.ean = a.ean 
                AND ( (  p.preisliste = "Test" AND p.iln = "2222222222222" ) OR (1=0) )

                # base color join
                LEFT JOIN farbenzuordnung zu ON 
                    a.farbe = zu.farbe 

                WHERE a.aktiv = "ja"
                # include currency if applicable
                AND ( IF( a.iln IN ( 2222222222222), p.onlinepreis IS NOT NULL,1 ) )

                AND a.artikelnummer LIKE "%style_number%"


            GROUP BY a.iln, a.artikelnummer
            HAVING (( sum(a.bestand) != 0 ) OR (a.nos = "ja" AND a.nos_anzeige = "ja" ))
            ) AS temp
```

I need to group by seller (`a.iln`) and style (`a.artikelnummer`). The `having` clause only selects products that have inventory (`sum(a.bestand) != 0`) or are available never-out-of-stock (`a.nos` set on product and `a.nos_anzeige` feature active).

My problem is selecting distinct sizes/colors done in these lines:

```
  , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT sizeRange ), ',', 10  ) AS sz_rng
  , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT colorRange ), ',', 10  ) AS cl_rng
   ....
  , a.groesse AS sizeRange
  , zu.systemfarbe AS colorRange
```

This does not work properly. The above article would return only `s,xl` vs `s,m,l,xl` and I'm not really sure why. I'm using the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to only select the first 10 sizes/colors (TOP 10 would be nicer), but I'm not sure this is the problem.

**Question:**
Is there something wrong in the syntax which causes not all distinct sizes/colors to be returned? Is there a way to only retur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. After playing around with this for a while and keeping @Shlomi Noach comment in mind, I came up with the following:

- also group by `a.groesse` and `zu.systemfarbe`
- this throws off the `recordcount` (seems I'm now no longer grouping by style number (`a.artikelnummer`)
- remove the `COUNT(recordcount) AS total_records` and use `COUNT(DISTINCT styles) AS total_records` instead with
  `a.artikelnummer AS styles` in the subquery.

So my query now looks like this:

```
 SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT styles) AS total_records
      , MIN(min_price_ek) AS ek_min
      , MAX(max_price_ek) AS ek_max
      , MIN(min_price_vk) AS vk_min
      , MAX(max_price_vk) AS vk_max
      , MAX(max_reb) AS rb_max
      , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT sizeRange ), ',', 10  ) AS sz_rng
      , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT colorRange ), ',', 16  ) AS cl_rng

      FROM (SELECT  
             a.artikelnummer AS styles
           , a.nos
           , a.nos_anzeige
           , MAX(IFNULL(p.ek, a.preis_ek)) AS max_price_ek
           , MIN(IFNULL(p.ek, a.preis_ek)) AS min_price_ek
           , MAX(IFNULL(p.vk, a.preis_vk)) AS max_price_vk
           , MIN(IFNULL(p.vk, a.preis_vk)) AS min_price_vk
           , ROUND( MAX(  ( IFNULL(p.ek, a.preis_ek) - IFNULL(p.vk ,a.preis_aktuell) ) /  IFNULL(p.ek, a.preis_ek)  ),2) AS max_reb
           , a.groesse AS sizeRange
           , zu.systemfarbe AS colorRange

           ...
            GROUP BY  a.iln, a.artikelnummera.groesse, zu.systemfarbe
            HAVING (( sum(a.bestand) != 0 ) OR (a.nos = "ja" AND a.nos_anzeige = "ja" ))
            ) AS temp
```

Seems to work and the query processing time also is about the same. I'm open for improvement suggestions tough if this can be done any other/easier way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**
Now I see your error. The inner query uses aggregation, and takes out `sizeRange` which is not a column you aggregate on. So you only get "samples" of that column. Strictly speaking, your query is not valid SQL but MySQL allows it given a relaxed `sql_mode`.

So your query is inherently erroneous. Will see if I can help fix it.

**ORIGINAL answer**

My guess for you would be to check the value of `group_concat_max_len`.

It is by default just `1024`, though you typically don't really want a limit for that.

The problem might be that you are only getting partial results, where, by chance or by order of evaluation, "S" and "XL" occupy first 1024 characters or more. I see no reason why "M" or "L" would not be there -- the `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't do such distinctions.

So, try out:

```
SET group_concat_max_len := 1000000;
```

And execute your query again. If this works, make sure to set said param in you MySQL configuration file.

You may find my [related post](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/those-oversized-undersized-variables-defaults) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the input so far. Good idea with length, but I tested running the query on a single article, which should only return: "s,m,l,xl" and I get "s,xl". So you are probably correct about the `inherent error`... :-)

Comment: Fixed it. See my answer. Thanks for helping out!